# Reset software and remove everything takes 2 days

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 7 laptop to Windows 10 via the desktop notification.

I downloaded and installed the update, but explorer.exe couldn't start (it was constantly crashing), so I launched a reset to clean Windows and remove all data (I selected the "remove everything" option).

When researching some subjects, I saw that the processes could take a long time if the hard drive is large and full. Since my hard drive is 750GB and almost full I expected the process to take almost a day, but the percent counter is now stuck at 32% since 40 hours.

I'm now wondering how to troubleshoot this, and what will happen if I force reboot. Is there any chance that the counter will restart?

Comment: What USB devices are plugged into your computer? Definitely don't kill the power now, unless you want to do a full reinstall from DVD.

Comment: First;  A 750GB HDD isn't large.  There are HDDs that are 10x that size on the market.  Second;  The fact it is stuck and has been stuck for 40 hours means you likely have a HDD that is in post fail condition.

Comment: No USB device plugged in at all, no USB key / external hard drive / mouse / keyboard. I'll ne forced to power out m'y computer in 2 days to travel with it, before that deadline i'd like to know if i can do anything but wait. And i know 750gb isn't the biggest, but i saw some threads on reddit where users talked about 6 hours delays for 300 gb drives, so i took my chance